# What will happen to my researched Prime Glyphs with patch 5.0?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a character with the Inscription skill and I research a new Prime Glyph every day, but Prime Glyphs are going away with patch 5.0.  Will I just lose all my researched glyphs or will they be converted into something?

Also, should I stop researching over the next month, as a waste of time and materials?

Comment: The PTR notes (http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/6761563) cryptically state "Prime glyphs have been removed."

Comment: Voting to close - "too localized".  This question's content is obsolete and I can see no way to salvage it.  http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5282/can-we-stop-closing-questions-that-have-become-obsolete-as-too-localized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can conclusively answer this for you: **Research done now will not be wasted.**

I just tested it - I transferred my character who had researched all glyphs on to the Mists of Pandaria Beta.  I checked Death Knight glyphs as a random selection.

There are [30 Death Knight glyphs](http://www.wowhead.com/items=16.6?filter=eb=1) in Cataclysm, including [11 Prime](http://www.wowhead.com/items=16.6?filter=cr=132;crs=3;crv=0;eb=1).  In Mists of Pandaria there are also [30 Death Knight glyphs](http://mop.wowhead.com/items=16.6?filter=eb=1), albeit a significantly different selection, and no Primes (obviously).

When I reviewed my Scribe's glyph list on the Mists of Pandaria beta, he had still all 30 Death Knight glyphs so **(almost?) any glyphs found now will transfer to a new glyph in Mists**.

Answer (score 4):

After reading some discussions about the preservation of ItemIds, I went to some data sites and confirmed that the vast majority of glyphs are either preserved or converted into new glyphs.

I would expect recipes to convert their outputs, glyphs in inventory/bank/AH to convert, and learned glyphs to convert as well.

Here are the glyph conversions for Mage... Note, these conversions may change before 5.0 goes live, but the intention to preserve (most of the) existing items is clear:

```
Prime

Arcane Blast -> Arcane Power (major)
Living Bomb -> Fire Blast (major)
Fireball -> Combustion (major)
Frostfire -> Frostfire Bolt (major)    
Cone of Cold -> Icy Veins (major)
Ice Lance -> Ice Lance (major)
Deep Freeze -> Water Elemental (major)

Arcane Barrage -> Illusion (minor)
Arcane Missiles -> Loose Mana (minor)
Molten Armor -> Crittermorph (minor)
Pyroblast -> Momentum (minor)

Frostbolt -> Faded Glyph (removed)

Major

Invisibility -> Invisibility 
Arcane Power -> Arcane Explosion
Mage Armor -> Mana Gem
Polymorph -> Polymorph
Slow -> Slow
Mana Shield -> Counterspell
Evocation -> Evocation
Blink -> Blink
Dragon's Breath -> Spellsteal
Blast Wave -> Remove Curse
Frost Armor -> Armors
Ice Barrier -> Deep Freeze
Ice Block -> Ice Block
Icy Veins -> Cone of Cold
Frost Nova -> Frost Nova

Minor

Arcane Brilliance -> Porcupine
Mirror Image -> Mirror Image
Conjuring -> Conjure Familiar
Armors -> Rapid Teleportation
Slow Fall -> Arcane Language
Penguin -> Penguin
Monkey -> Monkey
```

Based on this information,  I plan to continue prime glyph research daily until the patch.